# How to create a mask for nd values in a 2d NumPy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, mask

If I want to create a mask depending on a 1d value in a 2d array:

```
a = np.array([[3, 5], [7, 1]])
threshold = 2
mask = a > threshold
print(a)
print(mask)
```

I get:

```
[[3 5]
 [7 2]]
[[ True  True]
 [ True False]]
```

How can I create such a mask for a 2d array with nd values? Like the following example of 2d values and a 2d threshold in a 2d array:

```
b = np.array([[[1, 5], [3, 5]], [[4, 4], [7, 2]]])
threshold = 2, 4
print(b)
```

Looks like this:

```
[[[1 5]
  [3 5]]

 [[4 4]
  [7 2]]]
```

`[1, 5]`, `[3, 5]`, `[4, 4]` and `[7, 2]` are the exemplary 2d values. The threshold, as set in `threshold`, for the first value is `2` and for the second value it's `4`:

- cell for `[1, 5]` should be `False` since `1 > 2 == False` and `5 > 4 == True`
- cell for `[3, 5]` should be `True` since  `3 > 2 == True` and `5 > 4 == True`
- cell for `[4, 4]` should be `False` since  `4 > 2 == True` and `4 > 4 == False`
- cell for `[7, 2]` should be `False` since  `7 > 2 == True` and `2 > 4 == False`

What do I have to do to get this corresponding mask?

```
[[ False  True]
 [ False False]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` broadcasted comparison actually handles this quite nicely for you.  Just make your `threshold` a `1D` array and assert `all` along the final axis.

```
t = np.array([2, 4])

(b > t).all(-1)
```

```
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

---

To clarify however, your array is actually `3D`. If your array was `2D`, like below, this would work a bit differently:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 5],
                [3, 5],
                [4, 4],
                [7, 2]])

(arr > t).all(-1)
```

```
array([False,  True, False, False])
```